# Sass output style doesn't update when changed

Tags: sass

I am using Sass 3.2.1 (Media Mark), and used "--watch main.scss:main.css --style compact
" for example, to output my css in that particular style. It appears the style changes will take effect **ONLY** after I trash the css file and open it.

If I return to the scss file and save it, the css returns to the default scss.
Shouldn't "--watch main.scss:main.css --style compact" make the output compact until i change it to --expanded, --compressed???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass won't recompile the CSS unless there is a change to your Sass files, even if you've switched your compression type.

Personally, I just have 2 different watches that output to 2 different directories.  The watch with `compact` is always running and outputs to my "production" directory that is in CVS.  The second watch using `expanded` is only running when I need to debug and it outputs to a directory that's set to be ignored by CVS.  This way, there's no accidentally committing the uncompressed version.

Comment: Do you do that by opening another terminal window and just make sass watch for another style? Sorry what is CVS?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple terminals running (or tmux).  I guess I should have said version control instead of CVS (I'm actually using Darcs).